# aspect ratio a calculation

Tags: math

afternoon all. Iv'e come across some mathematical problems that im not too good at. does anyone know how to calculate the ratio for Height against width?

Regards Phil

Comment: Phil Jackson is pretty tall. He'd have a high aspect ratio.

Comment: surely there must be more? h= 344 w = 543 the ratio would be ??:?? i would be using this in a javascript

Comment: PLease provide more information about what you are trying to do ! Otherwise height / width seems like the perfect answer

Comment: it's a matter of fraction simplification. 344/543 is irreductible, so your aspect ratio here would be 543:344.

play a bit with http://www.wolframalpha.com/ if you're not familiar with fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple function that should give you the aspect ratio (simplified and in javascript)

```
function getAspectRatio(w, h)
    {
        var rem;
        var newW = w;
        var newH = h;

        while (h != 0)
        {
            rem = w % h;
            w = h;
            h = rem;
        }

        newH = newH / w;
        newW = newW / w;

        alert("Aspect Ratio: " + newW + ":" + newH);
    }
```

`getAspectRatio(800,600);` results in `4:3`.

Hope this helps

G

EDIT: I forgot to mention, it calculates the gcd of the two numbers and does not check for division by zero, so you might want to add that. :)

Comment: keeps returning NaN:NaN

function calcRatio(){
     $(".heightAndWidth").keypress(function (e) {
      var rem;
      var newW = 20;
      var newH = 100;
    
      while (h != 0){
       rem = w % h;
       w = h;
       h = rem;
      }
      newH = newH / w;
      newW = newW / w;
      alert("Aspect Ration : " + newW + ":" + newH);      
     });
    }

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
newWidth = newHeight / oldHeight * oldWidth
```

OR

```
newHeight = newWidth / oldwidth * oldHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the aspect ratio of a height and width, it's just height / width reduced to its greatest common factor.

For instance, if your monitor is 1600 x 1200, it's 1600/1200 reduced to 4/3.  To do this:

In math terms, you have to find the "Greatest Common Factor" and divide both values (1600 and 1200) by that.  In this case, it's 400.

A **very** simple (and relatively) algorithm for this is:

```
for i <= min( 1600, 1200 ); i > 0; --i );
  if( 1600 % i == 0 && 1200 % i == 0 ) {
    minTop = 1600 / i;
    minBottom = 1200 / i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Your answer is minTop / minBottom.  Replace 1600 and 1200 with the width and height you want, respectively.

Basically, the algorithm goes like this: count down from the lesser of the two numbers and find the first number into which both 1600 and 1200 divide into evenly (using the mod operator, so remainder == 0).  That will end up being 400.  That leads you with (1600 / 400) / (1200 / 400), or 4/3.

Hope this helps; leave a comment with any questions and I'll try to help further.

Comment: what ? how do you go programmatically from 1333/1000 to 4/3 ??

Comment: Easiest way to do that is to multiply both by 1000, round off, and then 
Multiply or divide?